# Qt: Error accessing files from NFS share

Tags: c++, linux, qt, nfs

I am working on a C++ app with Qt 4.8. I am mounting an NFS share on /mnt/. The NFS server is on a Windows Server 2016.

mount command: `mount -t nfs 192.168.1.5:/NFS_SHARE /mnt/nfs_repo/`

When mounting the share on the client side (linux), I can navigate within the share, read all the files in it,etc...

In the Qt application, I can navigate through the share, but I can't see the files in the folders.

Example, I can access a folder within the share:

```
QDir nfsDir("/mnt/nfs_repo/test/test2/);
if(nfsDir.exists())
        qDebug() << "The repo " << nfsDir.path() << " is accessible"; //this outputs The repo /mnt/nfs_repo/test/test2 is accessible.

QStringList fileList = nfsDir.entryInfoList(QDir::AllEntries); //fileList is empty after this
```

When the share is mounted, it has weird permissions:

[image: Access rights]

Here is the configuration on the Windows Server Side. ALL MACHINES have Read/write permissions:

[image: Windows Server NFS config]

**- Is there any restrictions in using QDir with NFS Share (already mounted) ?**

**- Am I missing something ?**

Any help or advices are welcome !

**EDIT1:**

I tried setting all the permissions to the mounted share with `chmod -R 777 /mnt/nfs_repo` but this still didn't work.

NFS Version used on Linux is **version 3**.
NFS Version used on Windows Server 2016 is, I think, **version 4.1**

[image]

Comment: Set the proper permissions to your mountpoint. Try this for testing `chmod 777 /mnt/nfs_repo/`

Comment: I tried this but still nothing, I have access to the folder but when listing the files inside the folder still nothing

Comment: can you see non-empty list if you specify any system directory (with some files inside) ?

Comment: Yes, if it is any other directory on the system (I reproduced the exact folder hierarchy with the same files locally), it works like a charm. I have a QStringList with every files in the folder listed. Thus, it clearly comes from the nfs share. Does the fact that UID and GUID have strange values can cause such a problem ?

Comment: Most probably it is. Try to mount with following format `mount -t nfs -o umask=0022,gid=XXX,uid=YYY 192.168.1.5:/NFS_SHARE /mnt/nfs_repo/`

Comment: I have "mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified": I should have precised that NFS client (on Linux) is version 3.